# How to have a physical copy of the Windows 10 that comes with my new laptop, that can be restored later

Tags: windows-10

We old guys remember the old times when, together with the new computer, you would find a CD with the title "Windows 95 OEM" which meant that, no matter what happened to the hard drive, you could always install the OS from scratch again.

That way, you could easily, e.g., buy a bigger hard drive later and install the OS again.

My new laptop comes with Windows 10 and I may want to upgrade to a solid state drive later or maybe to a bigger hard drive.

Is there any way I can make a physical copy of this Windows 10 for that purpose? I can't find any option for that.

Comment: Installing Windows, unlike your outdated opinion suggests, has never been easier! You can download the ISO image file and the tool to make a bootable installation USB directly from Microsoft for any Windows, 7, 8 or 10. But you can also image the installed system using any of the available tools for that purpose. However, in order to later restore it in a working (bootable) state you need to clone/image at least the Windows system partitition *and* the ESP (EFI System Partition). So, everything is as before but easier and faster.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks! (+1) Why don't you write this as an answer, maybe with one or two screen captures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to accomplish this:

- Make an image of your hard drive using a tool such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), or just the operating system files:

[image: Backup OS]

- [Download the Windows 10 ISO and create bootabe media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), e.g. on a USB flash drive or DVD.

It's *always* a good idea to have a whole drive image when making hardware changes, anyway, in case damage to files occurs.